# Where is the hash command documentation?

Tags: bash, command, documentation

When I type `man hash` it shows me `man builtin`.

I'm trying to understand this line:

```
hash -r 2>/dev/null || true
```

What `hash -r` does and what it returns.

Context:

```
export PATH="$PWD/bin:$PATH"
hash -r 2>/dev/null || true
```

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs#adding-project-specific-binstubs-to-path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hash` is a shell builtin.

If you are using `bash`, check:

```
help hash
```

For your convenience, here it is:

> hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
>
> ```
> Remember or display program locations.
>
> Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.  If
> no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is displayed.
>
> Options:
>   -d                forget the remembered location of each NAME
>   -l                display in a format that may be reused as input
>   -p pathname       use PATHNAME as the full pathname of NAME
>   -r                forget all remembered locations
>   -t                print the remembered location of each NAME, preceding
>             each location with the corresponding NAME if multiple
>             NAMEs are given
> Arguments:
>   NAME              Each NAME is searched for in $PATH and added to the list
>             of remembered commands.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns success unless NAME is not found or an invalid option is given.
> ```

For other shells, check the usual place for builtins. For example, for `zsh`, check:

```
man zshbuiltins
```

---

> What hash -r does and what it returns.

`hash -r` removes all remembered locations from the hash table and it returns success.

Answer (score 1):

hash is a standardized shell builtin and `hash -r` resets the current path hash that is used to locate comands in `PATH`.

Calling `hash -r` after setting `PATH` is however not needed as changing `PATH` automatically resets the current command hashing. This is true for the `Bourne Shell` and for `ksh` and I would expect other shells to behave the same way.